# Source separation of a mixture of mixtures

Tags: multivariate-analysis, gaussian-mixture-distribution, signal-processing

I am quite new to ML / DSP so I apologise if the answer is obvious to others. I am comfortable with complex software implementation, and have a degree focussed on statistics, but little experience with mixtures / separation. Thank you for your help.

**Optional Background Information**

I am analysing [qPCR melting curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melting_curve_analysis) data. This is a method for determining the presence of particular DNA sequences in a specimen by measuring fluorescence levels. DNA has two strands and an added fluorescent molecule only glows when these strands are joined; increasing the temperature causes the DNA to separate ("melt") thus reducing fluorescence. Different sequences melt at different temperatures.

For F = fluorescence and T = temperature we are interested in -dF/dT as the modes represent the melting temperatures of the sequences present. -dF/dT is well-described when modeled as a Gaussian mixture model with one component per DNA sequence. For the purpose of my analysis, the number of components is always 2 although one may be negligible (i.e. the model is just a regular Gaussian).

The equipment simultaneously analyses two fluorescence channels (let's refer to them as red and blue) each with its own sensor. Sensing is imperfect which results in the red channel sampling predominantly red with some blue, and vice versa. This results in enough overlap to occasionally cause aberrant results.

This is analogous to 2 "well-placed" microphones recording 2 distinct 2-component Gaussian processes.

**Question**

Given:

- Two sources: *a* & *b*
- Two signals: *A* & *B*

We know that:

- Sources *a* & *b* are independent and *differently* distributed; each is the additive combination of 2 different Gaussian processes (1 of which may be negligible, rendering the source a simple Gaussian).
- There are reliable estimates of the means of each of the 4 possible processes making up *a* & *b*; within a source we know that potential means are different enough that the histogram is bimodal, but between sources this is not necessarily the case (i.e. given that *a* or *b* has 2 non-negligible processes it will always be bimodal, but *a* + *b* may not be).
- Signal *A* is composed predominantly of source *a*, but includes some of *b*, and vice versa for signal *B*.
- Signals *A* & *B* are both well-described when modeled as 2-component Gaussian mixture models.

**What is your recommendation for the best approach to identify signals *a* & *b* if I have parameters for the mixture models of *A* & *B*?**

The results that I am seeing are such that the modes of the signals are being shifted along the domain as well as being "enhanced" (but not suppressed). The presence and x-positions of modes (as proxies for significant component contributions) are of most interest in my analysis.

I am aware that ICA requires non-Gaussian sources. Given that inter-signal component processes are likely similar (in mean, but still independent), I believe that PCA may also be inappropriate.

Please let me know if graphs of the signals will make this clearer.

**Implementation Caveat**

I have to do this in JavaScript so please recommend algorithmic approaches rather than implementations such as scikit-learn. The users of the software have overbearing IT restrictions that make it exceptionally difficult for me to install / update software for them (hence a browser interface). Additionally they have restrictions on data being sent to external servers (hence client-side processing).

**Updates**

I suspect that this can be treated as some basic linear algebra although the outcome requires some additional information. If we let *g* be the siGnal row vector [A B], *r* be the souRce row vector [a b] then we have some weighting coefficients in the 2x2 matrix W such that g = rW, and r = g(W^-1). The problem then becomes estimating W. Suggestions?

Comment: I've since discovered that colour compensation data exists in order to correct for the channel mixing. I suspect that this renders my problem impossible as is, but I will leave it as the general problem (i.e. not applied to qPCR) may be interesting.

http://lifescience.roche.com/wcsstore/RASCatalogAssetStore/Articles/lc_ApplicationNote19.pdf